# Tkinter - setting height with grid manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to build simple GUI application using Tkinter and Python. The application should look more or less like that

```
------------------------------
Label-1 | Canvas-1
------------------------------
Label-2 | Canvas-2
------------------------------
Label-3 | Canvas-3
------------------------------
 . . .
Label-3 | Canvas-3
------------------------------
        | scrollbar-horizontal
------------------------------
```

where scrollbar should scroll across all `Canvas` objects at the same time. That part I was able to accomplish but I am facing issues when I am trying to set height for each of row. Basically I want row one under the other with predefined height. I decided to use grid manager to achieve that.

Below is a minimal example:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.font


class LineData(object):

    def __init__(self, desc, box):
        self.desc = desc
        self.box = box

class LinePlotter(object):

    def __init__(self, label, canvas, desc, box):
        self.label = label
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.desc = desc
        self.box = box

    def plot(self):
        self.label.set(self.desc)
        x1, y1 = self.box[0], 1
        x2, y2 = self.box[1], 20
        print(self.desc)
        print(x1, y1, x2, y2)
        print(x2+100, y1, x2+(x2-x1)+100, y2)
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, outline="#D1D0CE", 
                                     width=4, fill="#D1D0CE")

        self.canvas.create_rectangle(x2+100, y1, x2+(x2-x1)+100, y2, outline="#D1D0CE",
                                     width=4, fill="#D1D0CE")


class Plotter(tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, lines_data):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.lines_data = lines_data

    def set_scroll_bar(self):
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.canvases[0].bbox(tkinter.ALL)
        x1 = y1 = 0
        for c in self.canvases:
            t1, u1, t2, u2 = c.bbox(tkinter.ALL)
            x1 = min(x1, t1)
            x2 = max(x2, t2)
            y1 = min(y1, u1)
            y2 = max(y2, u2)

        print("final=", x1, y1, x2, y2)
        for c in self.canvases:
            c.config(scrollregion=(x1-5, y1-5, x2+5, y2+5))

    def xview(self, *args):
        for c in self.canvases:
            c.xview(*args)

    def initUI(self):

        self.scrollX = tkinter.Scrollbar(self, orient=tkinter.HORIZONTAL)

        self.scrollX['command'] = self.xview
        self.scrollX.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='NSEW')

        self.canvases = []

        h = 10
        for row_idx, line_data in enumerate(self.lines_data):
            desc = tkinter.StringVar()
            font = tkinter.font.Font(size=11)
            label = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=desc, font=font, 
                                  height=h)
            label.grid(row=row_idx, column=0, sticky=tkinter.W)

            canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self, bg='white', 
                                    xscrollcommand=self.scrollX.set, 
                                    height=h)

            line = LinePlotter(desc, canvas, line_data.desc, line_data.box)
            line.plot()

            canvas.grid(row=row_idx, column=1, sticky=tkinter.W)
            self.canvases.append(canvas)

        self.set_scroll_bar()

        self.pack(expand=True, fill=tkinter.X)


l1 = LineData("L1", (50, 60))
l2 = LineData("L2", (200, 250))

root = tkinter.Tk()

Plotter(root, [l1, l2]).initUI()
root.mainloop()
```

When I set `h = None` in `initUI`, I see that objects are expanding to whole window

[image]

When I set `h = 10`, I see that rows are getting thinner but they are distributed all along screen.

[image]

And when I set `h = 50`, I see only the first line.

[image]

Ideally I would like to see something like with `h = 10` but one row under the other. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Are you expecting `h` to represent a height in pixels, or in a number of lines in the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `h` represents pixels when creating the canvas, but the number of lines when configuring the label. Use it for one or the other, but not both.

Assuming you want the canvas to be 10 pixels tall, simply remove the height from the label. This will allow the label to be as small as possible. It will still be taller than 10 pixels, but you can fix that by picking a smaller font.

When I simply remove `height=h` from the label, I end up with this:

[image]